# Is there a more efficient way to return the record of maximum spatial intersection in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, geometry

I have two tables in SQL.  The first are project polygons.  The second is any boundary I want to apply to the project polygons based on maximum spatial intersection.

For example, if project 1 is overlapping 2 states, I want to return the state name that project 1 has the most area in.

I've done so with the query below.  PrjID is the projects table and STATE is the state table.  I want to have statename returned based on maximum intersection between each PrjID record and STATE record.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT a.PROJECT_DELIVERY_ID, b.statename, a.Shape.STIntersection(b.Shape).STArea() AS Area
    FROM PrjID a
        INNER JOIN STATE b
            ON a.Shape.STIntersects(b.Shape) = 1) as c
INNER JOIN
(SELECT a.PROJECT_DELIVERY_ID, MAX(a.Shape.STIntersection(b.Shape).STArea()) AS Area
    FROM PrjID a
        INNER JOIN STATE b
            ON a.Shape.STIntersects(b.Shape) = 1
    GROUP BY a.PROJECT_DELIVERY_ID) as d
ON c.PROJECT_DELIVERY_ID = d.PROJECT_DELIVERY_ID
    AND c.Area = d.Area
```

I feel like I'm running the same query twice and joining them.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I do not understand the first subselect, why are you not just executing the second subselect?

Comment: It' sql-server 2012

Comment: Answers from The Impaler and Serkan Arslan work great.  Those are very helpful.  I'm trying to figure out which one is more efficient so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the second "table expression" can be built up from the first one, you could use a CTE (Common Table Expression), as in:

```
with
c as (
  SELECT
    a.PROJECT_DELIVERY_ID, 
    b.statename,
    a.Shape.STIntersection(b.Shape).STArea() AS Area
  FROM PrjID a
  INNER JOIN STATE b ON a.Shape.STIntersects(b.Shape) = 1
),
d as (
  select PROJECT_DELIVERY_ID, max(Area) AS Area
  from c
  group by PROJECT_DELIVERY_ID
)
select * 
from c
join d on c.PROJECT_DELIVERY_ID = d.PROJECT_DELIVERY_ID
    AND c.Area = d.Area
```

Here `d` is computed from `c`. No need to scan the table `PrjID` or `STATE` again.

Comment: The other answer works great too.  I chose this one based off of comments in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233125/is-there-a-performance-difference-in-using-a-group-by-with-max-as-the-aggregat)

Answer (score 2):

if I got it correct, you want to get max area row. you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT a.PROJECT_DELIVERY_ID, b.statename, a.Shape.STIntersection(b.Shape).STArea() AS Area, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.PROJECT_DELIVERY_ID ORDER BY a.Shape.STIntersection(b.Shape).STArea() DESC) RN
        FROM PrjID a
            INNER JOIN STATE b
                ON a.Shape.STIntersects(b.Shape) = 1 ) AS T
WHERE RN = 1
```