# SQL: select unique rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct

This is a "toy" example of a table that has many columns and 100s of thousands of rows.

I want *FILTER OUT* any rows containing the same AcctNo, CustomerName and CustomerContact, but KEEP the ID for *ONE* of the duplicates (so i can access the record later).

- Example:

  ```
  ID  AcctNo  CustomerName  CustomerContact
  1   1111    Acme Foods    John Smith
  2   1111    Acme Foods    John Smith
  3   1111    Acme Foods    Judy Lawson
  4   2222    YoyoDyne Inc  Thomas Pynchon
  5   2222    YoyoDyne Inc  Thomas Pynchon
  <= I want to save IDs 2, 3, and 5
  ```
- Fiddle:
  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bEECHi6XnvKAeXC4Xthrrr/1

Q: What SQL do I need to accomplish this?

Comment: And how is ID 3 a duplicate?

Comment: You might consider using the `row_number()` function.

Comment: Please share what sql you already tried.

Comment: You need the maximum Id for each group...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select MAX(ID) as KeepID,AcctNo,CustomerName,CustomerContact 
from test
GROUP BY AcctNo,CustomerName,CustomerContact
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically what you want is, partition your table by AcctNo, CustomerName and CustomerContact. It's unclear in the question how you want select which ID you need to keep, but for that you need to modify the the following query. But this should give you a starting point.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   test 
       JOIN (SELECT id, 
                    Row_number() 
                      OVER ( 
                        partition BY acctno, customername, customercontact) rn 
             FROM   test) A 
         ON test.id = A.id 
WHERE  A.rn = 1
```

This should return something like this:

| ID | AcctNo | CustomerName | CustomerContact | id | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11111 | Acme Foods | John Smith | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 11111 | Acme Foods | Judy Lawson | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 22222 | Yoyodyne Inc. | Thomas Pynchon | 4 | 1 |

What this is doing is basically first calculating row num based on the partition criteria and then picking only one row per partition.

Comment: Please don't use images for data... use formatted/tabular text.

Comment: @Pradatta - 1) In answer to your comment above, I tried many things ... but I didn't want to "clutter" my question with a bunch of failed attempts.  2) Regarding your reply: I *considered* partitions and row_number(), but I would have preferred a simpler solution.  Like [Robert Sheahan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66995135/3135317).  3) Do you know which approach would be more "efficient" (for large-ish datasets)?

Comment: @FoggyDay The MAX with Group By is more efficient I think.
Here's a nice explanation why:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233125/is-there-a-performance-difference-in-using-a-group-by-with-max-as-the-aggregat

Comment: Excellent citation - Thank you.