SQL unique values for one column
I have data composed of three columns. I would like to get distinct values for 2 columns only (ID, value).
Here is my data:
enter image description here
I would like to have this desired result:
enter image description here
I have tried SELECT DISTINCT..

For the date column, do you want the earliest date for each Id-value pair?

@Kevin The image Kalixon provided suggests that we do want the earliest date for each pair.

Which dbms are you using? The best answer for one product might not the best for another.

20 year old dates. Lazy Uni?

You can get the desired result if you group by ID,Value
 SELECT MIN(Date) as [Date], ID,Value
 FROM Table1
 GROUP BY ID,Value

fiddle



Date
ID
Value




7/12/2004
1
A


7/12/2004
2
B


7/12/2004
3
A


8/12/2004
2
C




A solution using Group By might provide better performance then ones using Row_Number. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233125/is-there-a-performance-difference-in-using-a-group-by-with-max-as-the-aggregat

You forgot to qualify one Date. BTW. are you sure OP is using MS SQL Server? AFAIK, both Oracle and Teradata use SQL standard " as delimiter. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words

missing order by

concat id and value and then do a distinct

@trillion I had an Order By in my original answer but found in this case I got the same results without it. Kalixon did not specify any sorting so I provided the most concise answer.

if you are looking for the desired output, here is the query:
SELECT date, ID, value
FROM (
  SELECT date, ID, value,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date, value ORDER BY ID) AS rn
  FROM your_table
) t
WHERE rn = 1;

this query is subquery with ROW_NUMBER() to assign a unique number to each row within each group date and value.
Output:
7/12/2004 | 1 | A
7/12/2004 | 2 | B
7/12/2004 | 3 | A
8/12/2004 | 2 | C


Based on the images it seems like you are just trying to fetch the first possible date based on a unique combination of the id and value columns.

first date or earliest date ---> Min() function per given
combination of fields i.e id and vale. ---> use of Group By
final
output should show the earliest date first ---> use order by by
default it is in Ascending Order


select 
  id, 
  value, 
  min(date) as first_date_at
from table
group by id, value
order by date 


